# make a bean run on application start. EJB3/websphere6.1/Java1.5

Tags: java, websphere, ejb-3.0, websphere-6.1

I am a little new to J2EE.  I have a EJB3 project and I want to run a class on application start-up, how can I do that?

I know in EJB3.1 I can use @startup and @singleton unfortunately that is not a option and I have to use EJb3 and java 5.  I have done some research and there were a few solutions but I have been unable to make it work.

Comment: This may help http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere Application Server version 6.1 does not support EJB3 with a standard installation. You also need to have a feature pack for EJB 3.0 installed.

See [this information](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21287579) on the IBM site.

If this is not your issue you should update your question with more detail of what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your only options prior to WebSphere 8 (with EJB 3.1 support) are:

- [WebSphere startup beans](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/asyncbns/tasks/tasb_confstb.html).  These are a programming model extension
- Package a WAR with the application, and use a ServletContextListener to initialize state used by the EJBs.